# winston logger file permission exception

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I have written an API using node.js ,in that used "`Winston logger`". In that the file i have mentioned to write all my logs has owner as "`ROOT`", so my application exited. When i change the file owner to "`my user`" my application works. So my conclusion is that the file permission is the problem.

My winston code:

```
new(winston.transports.File)({
        filename: config.path,-------------------->/home/username/logsdir/logfile
        //maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 10, // 10MB
        exitOnError: false,
        maxsize: 1024 * 1024,
        level: 'info',
        handleExceptions: true,
        levels: customLevels.levels,
        rotationFormat: function() {
            return getFormattedDate();
            function getFormattedDate() {
                var temp = new Date();
                return dateStr = padStr(temp.getFullYear()) + padStr(1 + temp.getMonth()) + padStr(temp.getDate()) + padStr(temp.getHours()) + padStr(temp.getMinutes()) + padStr(temp.getSeconds());
            }
            function padStr(i) {
                return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : "" + i;
            }
        }
    })]
```

Winston is not throwing any exception, simply my application exited. IS it possible to check the owner of a file, Or winston has any option to tackle this. I googled a lot but i cant find the solution. Help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Winston appears not to provide any help for such cases. The solution is to check for yourself if the file is writable. Here's one way to do so:

```
const paths = [
    '/var/log/my-app.log',
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'my-app.log'),
    path.join('/tmp', 'my-app.log'),
];

let logFile

for (const p of paths) {
    if (logFile) return

    try {
        let fh = fs.openSync(p, 'a');
        console.log(`logging to ${p}`)
        logFile = p
        fs.closeSync(fh)
    }
    catch (e) {
        // console.error(e.message)
    }
}
```

Now the variable logFile will have the name of a writable file, if one is writable.